# Fillable form values missing after pdf merge in php

Tags: php, pdf, fpdi

I am merging two pdfs using FPDI extended class like this.

```
function concat() {
    foreach ($this->files AS $file) {
        $page_count = $this->setSourceFile($file);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $page_count; $i++) {
            $tplidx = $this->ImportPage($i);
            $s = $this->getTemplatesize($tplidx);
            if (strpos($file, 'test') || strpos($file, 'test_slip')) {
                $this->AddPage('L', array($s['w'], $s['h']));
            } else {
                $this->AddPage($this->DefOrientation, array($s['w'], $s['h']));
            }
            $this->useTemplate($tplidx);
        }
    }
}
```

When I output the merged file, One pdf with fillable field elements had all the elements vanished like the text and barcode etc on that. The other form however is fine. When I echo the fillable pdf form it works great but after this merge I loose all my data from that.

I would appreciate any pointers on this issue.

Comment: Do the two forms have field names in common?

Comment: @MaxWyss No they do not have anything in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FPDI does not support importing of form fields](https://www.setasign.com/support/faq/fpdi/after-importing-a-page-all-form-fields-are-gone/#question-85).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any workaround for this that might help me. May be convert this fillable pdf form to a normal pdf somehow ?

Comment: @Shrav We (Setasign) offer other tools, which may help you but they are not free. You can use the [SetaPDF-Merger](https://www.setasign.com/merger) component to concatenate PDF documents including form fields or the [SetaPDF-FormFiller](https://www.setasign.com/formfiller) to e.g. flatten form fields.